# Identify which TreeItem has been selected in a Google Apps Script Tree

Tags: tree, google-apps-script

I'm implementing a treeView for the first time in Google Apps Script and running into some trouble.

This handler does get fired ok when selecting a treeItem

```
tree.addSelectionHandler(app.createServerSelectionHandler("restClick"));
```

I was expecting to be able to identify the selected item in the handler

```
function restClick(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  Logger.log(e.parameter.source);
  var tree = app.getElementById(e.parameter.source);
  Logger.log(tree.getId());
  return app;
}
```

The above code identifies the tree object correctly - however I can't figure out how to get the selectedItem - there is no appropriate method such as getSelectedItem() and there is no useful property of (e) that helps either

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=307). You should follow the link and star this issue to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it. On the issue comments there's an explanation for a somewhat cumbersome workaround, if this is really important to you.

The "tree object" should work like all others widgets on Apps Script, having a `setName` method where we could get on the handler event parameters item name or index (after adding the tree as a callback element in the handler using the `addCallbackElement`) e.g.

```
tree.setName('mytree').addSelectionHandler(app.createServerSelectionHandler("restClick").
    addCallbackElement(tree));
```

But this does not work, as informed in the bug report.

Comment: Henrique, Thank you for you rapid comment. However, tree object strangely does not have a setName() method- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_tree.

Comment: You're right, there's no `setName` method. And search a little more I found that it is not possible to get the selected item like this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Henrique, thank you for pointing me at that bug report. I took a look at the workaround but i don't think that approach will work for me. I'll just wait till it's fixed. Thank you again. Bruce

Comment: I believe this now works with `e.parameter.selected` here a [working example](https://sites.google.com/a/lagaroo.com.br/dev-test/dev-test/dev-test-multiple-folders)